# Does it make a difference whether I put WHERE conditions in the WHERE or Join clause, unrelated to the join?

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, query-optimization

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id 
  AND b.col = 'something'
```

vs

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id 
WHERE b.col = 'something'
```

I would assume that MySQL's query optimizer would regard this the same query. Are they the same in all such cases, whether the WHERE column is on table a or table b?

Comment: just as a good rule of thumb it should be you JOIN things on the JOIN and you filter things on the WHERE.. that way you can read it more easily and you can refactor it later with more ease

Comment: @JohnRuddell But are they both executed the same way, thus making performance the same?

Comment: Yes from what I know execution would be the same.. I've just seen so many queries that use either that logic or the opposite.. Joining tables and using the where to finish the join.. Its not bad, but its generally harder to read. All good programmers should get in a habit of doing things a certain way.. If you want to do it t this way just try to keep it that way all the time. Consistency is the key. I would recommend using the where for what its meant for and the join for what its meant for but that's my personal preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These queries will be handled the same way by MySQL. You can verify this by placing EXPLAIN EXTENDED in front of either query and looking over the Query Execution Plan. If you need a good resource for understanding the output of the EXPLAIN query, check out http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/ (if that link ever breaks, search the web for "Understanding MySQL Explain" and you'll have no trouble finding a resource.

In general, I would recommend the second form you used. It's not so much a matter of technical reasons related to query execution as it is related to ease of modifying code later on, when/if you need to. For example, suppose you added four or five more joins. It would be difficult to read this query if WHERE clauses were sprinkled all over the place.

Keeping your join clauses and your WHERE filters separate is definitely something I would consider a best practice, but it's to do with ease of reading/editing, not because you're gonna end up with a different query execution plan (unless you make a mistake, which I think most people would be more likely to do with the first query as opposed to the second)

Comment: I would also add that I agree with @JohnRuddel above... it's ultimately a matter of preference, and it's far more important that you are consistent. That being said, you'll be consistent with more SQL developers if you do it the second way vs the first. It's just a bit easier to read and manage, at least in my experience (and I imagine many others as well).